# PrimgNG + Angular Required field Validator for dropdown

Tags: angular, scrollview, requiredfieldvalidator, autofocus, primeng-dropdowns

I'm using a PrimeNG dropdown component and need to trigger a required field validation. when I click on form submit browser level validations is showing only error message. but I want dropdown + error message to be displayed. this behaviour is only in p-dropdown it's working fine for other primeng components.

[this is the behaviour on form submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7FkQ.png)

Here my code

```
<p-dropdown #p (onFocus)="isDropDownClicked?'':p.overlayVisible = true;" (onBlur)="p.overlayVisible = isDropDownClicked" (onClick)="isDropDownClicked=true" (onHide)="isDropDownClicked=false" [options]="List" [(ngModel)]="reservation" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Select" optionLabel="label" dropdownIcon="pi pi-caret-down" required [showClear]="false"> </p-dropdown>
```

[I want to display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyEUk.png)

Comment: share your minimal code so we can clarify your problem

Comment: this is not proper way edit your existing question

Comment: Please update your question with your minimal code

Comment: if you write `required` then it will by default `false` in primeng dropdown so When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

Comment: yes but when focus is going to that field only message is displayed, we need to scroll again to show the dropdown.